# OpenVPN does not work with Gateway, but does with bridge

Tags: openvpn, vpn, bridge, gateway

i want use openvpn on Linux Mint. When i tries the VPN connection (i am client) i writes these commands :

```
sudo openvpn --config file.tcp.ovpn
```

then my authorization

```
Enter Auth Username: user_xy
```

and

```
Enter Auth Password: *********
```

everything seems fine and terminal prints "Initialization Sequence Completed".

I found out if my router is in "Bridge mode" the openVPN works correctly, but if i set the "Gateway mode" openvpn does not work.
I also use VPN application on my mobile phone (it is not openVPN but "TURBO-VPN") and there all works great with both router mode.
I have requirement that I need the gateway mode on my router because of NAT.

**additional information :**

The modes on router set over http here :

[image]

Comment: In the router you should select "Gateway". Than read the contents of you file `less file.tcp.ovpn`. You need to find out the Protocol Type - in your case TCP i guess - and the Protocol Port. When u have these informaiton you have to create firewall / nat rules in your router.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create NAT rules on your router. Looking on this scenario from internet perspective, create `forward port TCP/UDP 1194` TO your computer inside local network (LAN). You need to tell your router, what to actually do with such traffic. That would be something like:

```
far OpenVPN peer -> internet -> your router -> forward UDP/TCP port 1194 packets to -> your computer inside LAN (eg. 192.168.1.5)
```

Make also sure that such traffic is allowed on the firewall (if is enabled).